# Print List object from String boot controller to view (HTML)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring Boot, please help me to fix this issue.

This is my controller mapping, I need to print all the properties of the list objects in my view.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ModelAttribute("todolist")
public List<Todo> getuser() {
    return  (List<Todo>) todoRepository.findAll();
}
```

This is my View, and a [link to my GitHub project](https://github.com/narenviswa/Todo-List). Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr th:each="message : ${todolist}">
        <td th:text="${todolist.title}">Title</td>
        <td th:text="${todolist.description}">Description</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `message` instead of `todolist`

```
<tr th:each="message : ${todolist}">
    <td th:text="${message.title}">Title</td>
    <td th:text="${message.description}">Description</td>
</tr>
```

Because `th:each` will iterate through the list of `todolist` and puts the value inside `message` property. Means `message` is your variable name for one element of the list. Would be better to call it `todo` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the response sorry i  forgot it..but still the html renders as  blank page with only Title and Description in it.

Comment: @NarenViswanath you need to give more information in your question what are u doing and whats works and whats not. And your github source looks quite ok for this controller?!?! [TodoController](https://github.com/narenviswa/Todo-List/blob/master/todo-list/src/main/java/io/naren/controller/TodoController.java)

Comment: I'm trying to get data from mysql and render it in my HTML view. I fetched it as object list and got stuck here. I don't know how to send  these objects to my view for printing it. I can submit the data from html to database from the same controller. The controller works well. New to Stack overflow sorry :P.

Comment: @NarenViswanath Show your full controller class please